# How to replace delimited spans with uniquely-numbered marked spans?

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, centos7

I have a file that spans of text delimited by `<BD>` **begin** and `<ED>` **end delimiters** with nesting permitted. I'm looking to change these delimiters to uniquely indicate each span of text between them. These delimiters can be arbitrary strings. For example:

```
%{                         # Begin delimiter <BD>
}%                         # End delimiter <ED>
```

and I'm looking to replace the delimiters with **uniquely-numbered markers**:

```
<BM><UniqueNumber><BM>     # <BD> is replaced by <BM>i<BM>
<EM><UniqueNumber><EM>     # <ED> is replaced by <EM>i<EM>
```

The `<BM>` and `<EM>` are arbitrary-length strings, can be binary, and are not present in the file being processed. For example, one could use `$'\x01'` for the `<BM>` and `$'\x02'` for the `<EM>` in most text files.

For example, a file contains delimited spans of text, including nested spans:

```
A %{ B
C %{ D
E }% F %{ G }% H }% I
J %{ K }% L
```

where the letters A..L can be any text. The transformation yields:

```
A <BM>0<BM> B
C <BM>1<BM> D
E <EM>1<EM> F <BM>2<BM> G <EM>2<EM> H <EM>0<EM> I
J <BM>3<BM> K <EM>3<EM> L
```

**Note:** I'm *not* looking for the numbering to indicate the nesting level; I am looking for each matching `<BM>i<BM>...<EM>i<EM>` span of text to be marked with **unique integers**, counting from 0 upwards.

And, I'd like to be able to store the maximum number **N** that is generated for marks **0..N-1**. I'm imagining the Bash function:

```
ChangeMarkup()
{
   local InputFile="$1"
   local OutputFile="$2"
   local BD="$3"   # Begin delimiter
   local ED="$4"   # End delimiter
   local BM="$5"   # Begin unique numbered marker
   local EM="$6"   # End unique numbered marker
   local -i N=0    
   # ... convert InputFile to OutputFile, incrementing N for each span
   echo "$N"       # Echo the number of spans
}

# Example invocation:
NSpans=$(ChangeMarkup infile outfile '%{' '}%' $'\x01' $'\x02')
```

The solution, I think, will be along the lines:

- Initialize `N=0`
- Scan for the `<BD>` and push `N` onto the stack. Replace `<BD>` with `<BM>$N<BM>`. Increment `N`.
- Scan for the `<ED>` and replace with `<EM><pop stack><EM>`
- At end, echo `$N`

I'm thinking that some **awk** in a Bash script might come to the rescue. I think this is beyond **sed**'s capabilities. I'm also open to **python** or any solution that can be written in a Bash script, restricted to using packages that are available within the **CentOS 7 Minimal iso**. Unfortunately, this means **perl** can't be considered.

Comment: `H }% I` instead of `H %} I` mistyping?

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. Yes, it was a typo... fixed!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, you can use `gnu-awk` and [RT special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records)

```
awk -v BD='%{' -v ED='}%' -v BM='<BM>' -v EM='<EM>' '
    BEGIN{i=c=-1; RS=BD"|"ED}
    RT==BD {++i; ++c; d[i]=c; tag=BM}
    RT==ED {tag=EM}
    {printf "%s%s%s%s",$0,tag,d[i],tag}
    RT==ED{--i; if(i==-1) tag=""}
' file
```

you get,

```
A <BM>0<BM> B
C <BM>1<BM> D
E <EM>1<EM> F <BM>2<BM> G <EM>2<EM> H <EM>0<EM> I
J <BM>3<BM> K <EM>3<EM> L
```

**EDIT: requirement (2)**

> if improper nesting is detected, that the script can return an error code? For example: %{ A }% }% the second  has no

```
awk -v BD='%{' -v ED='}%' -v BM='<BM>' -v EM='<EM>' '
    BEGIN{i=c=-1; RS=BD"|"ED}
    RT==BD {++i; ++c; d[i]=c; tag=BM}
    RT==ED {tag=EM}
    {
        if(i<0 && tag!=""){
            print "Error <ED> without opener" > "/dev/stderr"
            exit 1
        }
        printf "%s%s%s%s",$0,tag,d[i],tag
    }
    RT==ED{--i; if(i==-1) tag=""}
    END{
        if(i!=-1){
            print "Error <BD> without closer" > "/dev/stderr"
            exit 1
        }
    }
' file
```

**EDIT: requirement (1)**

> to allow for the  and  to be escaped? That is, if there is a backslash in front of these delimiters, then they're not treated as delimiters

and  escaped are `\%{` and `\}%` for example

```
awk -v BD='%{' -v ED='}%' -v BM='<BM>' -v EM='<EM>' '
    BEGIN{i=c=-1; RS="\\\\"BD"|\\\\"ED"|"BD"|"ED}
    RT==BD {++i; ++c; d[i]=c; tag=BM}
    RT==ED {tag=EM}
    RT~/^\\/{printf "%s%s",$0,RT; next}
    {
        if(i<0 && tag!=""){
            print "Error <ED> without opener" > "/dev/stderr"
            exit 1
        }
        printf "%s%s%s%s",$0,tag,d[i],tag
    }
    RT==ED{--i; if(i==-1) tag=""}
    END{
        if(i!=-1){
            print "Error <BD> without closer" > "/dev/stderr"
            exit 1
        }
    }
' file
```

with input file

```
A %{ B
C %{ D
E }% F %{ G }% H }% I
J %{ K }% L\%{ M\}%O
```

you get,

```
A <BM>0<BM> B
C <BM>1<BM> D
E <EM>1<EM> F <BM>2<BM> G <EM>2<EM> H <EM>0<EM> I
J <BM>3<BM> K <EM>3<EM> L\%{ M\}%O
```

Comment: Looking good... can this solution be adapted in 2 ways: (1) to allow for the `<BD>` and `<ED>` to be escaped?  That is, if there is a backslash in front of these delimiters, then they're not treated as delimiters.  And, (2) if improper nesting is detected, that the script can return an error code?  For example: `%{ A }% }%`  the second `<ED>` has no `<BD>`.

Comment: I'm also seeing at the end `<EM><EM>` and the final newline from the input file is not being emitted.

Comment: Yes, both requirements are possible

Comment: Thanks... if you have time to update the solution with these "extra credit" items, I think it will not only benefit me, but also others in seeing how error detection might be possible.  Huge thanks!

Comment: Turning incredible!  I've tried some variations to use backslashes, but haven't quite got that to work. Can an arbitrary escape work as in defining `-v ESC='#'` or `-v ESC='\\'`?  Also, I'm seeing `RT=="}%"` in the script body that can be replaced by `RT==ED`.

Comment: @SteveAmerige for you can use backslashes, `BEGIN{i=c=-1; RS="\\\\"BD"|\\\\"ED"|"BD"|"ED}` and `RT~/^\\/{printf "%s%s",$0,RT; next}`